# ordenar divs mediante jquery

Tags: jquery

Buen día a todos, estoy tratando de ordenar varios divs pero no lo he conseguido, mi html es el siguiente:

```
<div id='div_Gral'>
  <div id='Empleado1' data-sort="43491">
     <div id='imgEmpleado1'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='Empleado2' data-sort="43491">
    <div id='imgEmpleado2'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='Empleado3' data-sort="43491">
    <div id='imgEmpleado3'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='Empleado4' data-sort="43491">
    <div id='imgEmpleado4'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mi propósito es mediante jquery ordenar los div con id 'Empleado#' ya que dinámicamente creo algunos y no se están ordenando, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#div_Gral > div').sort(function (a, b) { 
    return $(b).data('sort') - (a).data('sort'); 
 }).appendTo('#div_Gral');
```

Asi obtengo el html donde tengo los divs:

```
var tbl = $('#div_Gral');
```

En seguida realizo lo siguiente para agregar un div:

```
var result = "<div id='Empleado2' data-sort="43491"><div id='imgEmpleado2'></div></div> "
tbl.append(result);
```

Y después de haber agregado ese div, tengo la función para ordenar:

```
$('#div_Gral > div').sort(function (a, b) { 
  return $(b).data('sort') - (a).data('sort'); 
}).appendTo('#div_Gral');
```

Pueden guiarme sobre como lo puedo resolver?

Comment: cuando dices que lo armas dinamicamente, utilizas algun array o lista?

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo donde armas dinamicamente

Comment: Te refieres a que los que creas dinamecamente no se ordenan, pero el resto si?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta. la primera vez q creo mi html si tengo todo ordenado, pero cuando deseo agregar uno nuevo, necesito q se ordene dependiendo valor que le pongo a data-sort="43491", ahi es donde ya no se ordena

Comment: Listo. tu comentario a sido mas conciso que la pregrunta, y no se te hace mas facil tener esa info en un array y despues volcarlo al html?, de esta forma cuando agregas un valor nuevo lo agregas al array, vuelves a ordenar el array y vuelcas todo al html.

Comment: Si, de hecho estaba haciendo algo similar, al volcar todo al html, pero es una aplicacion que usa websockets y asp.net, entonces al estar realizando eso cierto tiempo, en la consola, me aparecia el error de recursos insuficientes, por eso opte por esta alternativa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He modificado el **`sort`** que ya tenías, si te fijas en ves de restar los valores estoy comparando los valores con el mayor (`>`) y al final solo reemplazo el contenido que esta dentro del html del `div_Gral`.

Espero te sirva de guía.

```js
$(function(){
 $('#btnOrdenar').on('click', function () {
  
  var divOrder = $("#div_Gral > div").sort(function (a, b) {
   return $(a).data("sort") > $(b).data("sort");
  });
  
  $("#div_Gral").html(divOrder);
    
 });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnOrdenar">Ordenar</button>
    
<div id='div_Gral'>
 <div id='Empleado2' data-sort="43492">
  <div id='imgEmpleado2'>2-imgEmpleado</div>
 </div>
 <div id='Empleado4' data-sort="43494">
  <div id='imgEmpleado4'>4-imgEmpleado</div>
 </div>
 <div id='Empleado1' data-sort="43491">
  <div id='imgEmpleado1'>1-imgEmpleado</div>
 </div>
 <div id='Empleado3' data-sort="43493">
  <div id='imgEmpleado3'>3-imgEmpleado</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Por cada vez que agregues información al contenido, solo debes de ejecutar:

```
var divOrder = $("#div_Gral > div").sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data("sort") > $(b).data("sort");
});

$("#div_Gral").html(divOrder);
```

Comment: Hola Orlando, no funciona el código. No pasa nada al presionar el botón. Debes revisarlo. Saludos!

Comment: A mi me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Que raro que ami no me funcione.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un código de ejemplo, lo importantes que siempre ordenes tus datos en el array **antes** de volcarlo a tu html. Si deseas agregar un nuevo elemento, lo único que debes hacer es enviarlo a tu array, ordenar y volcar todo de nuevo en tu html.

```js
//arreglo de datos que se usa para crear dinamicamente mis div.
    var empleados = [
      {id:5, nombre:"fran"},
      {id:3, nombre:"juan"},
      {id:2, nombre:"carlos"},
      {id:6, nombre:"pedro"},
    ]

    //Función inicial que uso para correr todo el código y crear mis elementos dinamicamente.
    function init(){
      //Obtengo el contenedor general.
      let contenedor = document.getElementById("div_gral");
      //Limpiamos el contenedor para evitar duplicar los datos.
      contenedor.textContent="";
      //ordeno mis datos.
      ordenarEmpleados();
      
      //una vez ordenados, recorro los datos y comienzo a crear mis elementos.
      empleados.forEach(function(elem){
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id",elem.id);
        div.textContent= "Nombre: "+elem.nombre+" ID: "+elem.id;
        contenedor.appendChild(div);
      });
      
    }

    function compare(a,b) {
    //Condiciones que se van a utilizar para ordenar el array
    //En este caso se va a ordenar por ID de menor a mayor.
      if (a.id < b.id)
        return -1;
      if (a.id > b.id)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }


    function ordenarEmpleados(){
     return empleados.sort(compare);
    }

    function guardarItem(){
      let item = {};
      item.id = document.getElementById("inputID").value;
      item.nombre = document.getElementById("inputNOMBRE").value;
      
      empleados.push(item);
      init();
      document.getElementById("inputID").value = "";
      document.getElementById("inputNOMBRE").value = "";
    }
    init();
```

```css
#div_gral{
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
Mi contenedor:
<div id="div_gral" ></div>
Agregar un nuevo elemento
<br>
<input id="inputID" type="text" placeholder="ingresar el id">
<input id="inputNOMBRE" type="text" placeholder="ingresar el nombre">
<button onclick="guardarItem()">Guardar</button>
```